# Como recarregar uma Directive do AngularJS no Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Saudações pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um app com login e estou utilizando o AngularJS, mas estou com uma dúvida cruel na hora de logar o usuário.

Acontece que eu estou utilizando o menu do usuário via Directive, quando o usuário não estar logado no sistema ele mostra os links padrões (Entrar, Registrar, etc...), mas mesmo após o usuário logar no sistema ele permanece o mesmo menu. Eu gostaria de quando o usuário fizesse o login ele recarregasse a Directive do menu para mostrar as opções de usuários.

A minha directive é à seguinte:

```
app.directive("menuAluno", function() {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }

  return {
    templateUrl: "menu",
    scope: { menuAluno: '=menuAluno' },
    controller: "menuCtrl"
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo sua directive ta muito vaga, na sua controller crie um objeto usuário e preencha ele com os dados do seu usuario vindo de onde você esta puxando, e deixa a directive só para o menu mesmo, exemplo:

```
app.directive("menuAluno", function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: scope.urlMenu,
    scope: {
       menuAluno: '=menuAluno',
       objAluno: '='
    },
    link: function(scope){
           scope.urlMenu = (scope.ubjAluno ? 'menu-aluno.html' : 'menu-defalt.html');
    },
    controller: "menuCtrl"
  };
});
```

no exemplo que deu acima eu recebo um objeto `objAluno` e logo no link verifico se o usuario esta preenchido(logado) `scope.urlMenu = (scope.ubjAluno ? 'menu-aluno.html' : 'menu-defalt.html');` se sim eu passo uma Url para o `templateUrl`, se não passo outra url para o template, ai la na sua pagina vc passa o objeto usuario como parametro para o componente exemplo `<menu-aluno obj-aluno="vm.usuario"></menu-aluno>`

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela resposta, tem algum jeito da directive ficar "vigiando" alteração do objeto para assim ele atualizar o menu sem precisar da refresh na página quando o usuário efetuar o login?

Comment: tem sim, vc pode colocar um $watch() dentro da directiva escutando o objAluno e quando ele for alterado ele executa o <code>scope.urlMenu = (scope.ubjAluno ? 'menu-aluno.html' : 'menu-defalt.html');</code> assim eles estaria verificando o valor do usuário sempre, de uma olhadinha no  $watch $apply e $digest para entender melhor o data bind do angularJS, aqui esta um exemplo do $whatch() http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/jmf6kL3n/ , nesse exemplo ele esta escutando um ng-model="myName" e dizendo se ele e maior ou meno que 5 caracteres

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez pelo o auxilio, irei fazer um teste... Fico muito grato. :)